# flask-admin list view is too slow for large table

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a table which has about 35,000,000 rows, It took more than 15 seconds to showing the list view of the table by using flask-admin, how can I speed it up?

Comment: What's the database, model definition and view definition? Install [Flask-DebugToolbar](https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and analyze the query/queries(!) being executed.

Comment: It's actually more depends on your database and table structure, more than on flask-admin. One of possible improvements, try to optimize count query.

Comment: I'm using postgresql, yes, the count query is too slow

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgresql  you can override flask-admin count function  using `pg_class` table which can return approximate count of table very fast

```
count = self.session.execute(
    """
    SELECT reltuples::bigint AS count
    FROM pg_class
    WHERE oid = '{0}'::regclass
    """.format(self.model.__table__.fullname)
).scalar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update based on the previous answer of Zaytsev Dmitry for Postgres with Flask-Admin V 1.5.3 and Python 3.

in `app/admin.py`

```
class ExampleView(ModelView):

    """
    your custom code
    """

    def get_count_query(self):
        return self.session.execute(
                                     f"""
                                      SELECT reltuples::bigint AS count
                                      FROM pg_class
                                      WHERE oid = 
                                      '{self.model.__table__.fullname}'::regclass
                                      """
                                    )
```